# Fail to set timezone in <f:convertDateTime>

Tags: jsf-2, timezone

I'am trying to get **timezone** property from backing bean but it fail because getter() is called before its value is initiated.

Here is pieces of code:

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{bean.startDate}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{msg['dateformat.yyymmdd']}"
    timeZone="#{bean.timezone}" />
</p:outputLabel>
```

And backing bean:

```
public void init(){
    timezone= getUserTimeZone();
}

public String getTimezone() {
    return timezone;
}
```

Can anyone explain why this happen?

Comment: Apparently you initiated it at the wrong moment? I'm not seeing a `@PostConstruct` annotation on `init()` method.

Comment: @BalusC I think it is correct, bean class have a `@ViewScoped`. It is fine with other property or that `timezone` property in another component attribute like p:outputLabel value

Comment: If it was correct you wouldn't have asked this question. Put `@PostConstruct` on that method.

Comment: @BalusC Thank you, it worked. Can I know why `@PostConstruct` is need in this situation?

Comment: If you don't use the `@PostConstruct` annotation your init method won't be hit unless you especifically invoke it from the view...

Comment: @XtremeBiker Yes. I do invoke it from the view with f:event